# The Xml file generated by swagger is empty in asp .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger

I have project file called XWebsite.csproj. I have added the swagger documentation and

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("XApiSpec",
                    new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo()
                    {
                        Title = "X Api",
                        Version = "v1",
                        Description = "X Website Apis"
                    });
                var xmlCommentFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var cmlCommentsFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentFile);
                options.IncludeXmlComments(cmlCommentsFullPath);
            });
            services.AddSwaggerDocumentation();
```

The swagger UI is showing in the browser but XML comments are not showing. I have already added XML comments in controllers.
The problem is, The file "**XWebsite.xml**" doesn't have these XML comments. Below is the content of "XWebsite.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>XWebsite</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
    </members>
</doc>
```

I have no idea why this file is not populated with comments.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Right click your project, and paste the path of xml file. It works for me.

[image]

[image]